# How to make vim not break strings when autoformating?

Tags: vim, autoformatting

I have a list of string values that I would like to autoformat but vim breaks the strings if there is a space inside of it.

Can this be fixed somehow?

example

```
    "sdasda", "asdasdasd", "afasfasf", "asdasda asdasd", "asdasd"
```

becomes

```
    "sdasda", "asdasdasd", "afasfasf", "asdasda
    asdasd", "asdasd"
```

but I want

```
    "sdasda", "asdasdasd", "afasfasf",
    "asdasda asdasd", "asdasd"
```

Extra bonus: It would be nice for it to support different string formatings (Python, ". ' and """)

Comment: There might be a trick using the syntax information for formatting, but this is above my vim skills. People hanging out on [vim_use](http://groups.google.com/group/vim_use) will probably find this one easy to answer.

Comment: It might be worth noting that I need it to support different string representation (python programmer so need support for " ' and """)

Comment: @Lumi I will give them the link to the question =) thanks

Answer (score 1):

This can be implemented via a custom `'formatexpr'` (that checks for an unclosed string quote before the cursor, and then performs the reformatting from that position instead of the insert position).

However, I haven't seen any custom `'formatexp'` in my many years of Vim use, so unless something turns up here or on vim_use [archives], you probably have to implement such a thing yourself (which is non-trivial if you also want to support re-formatting via `gq`, and requires a decent knowledge of Vimscript).