# How to keep vim from breaking string literals?

Tags: python, vim, line-breaks

This sounds like a very basic question that probably has an obvious solution, I haven't found it, unfortunately.

How do I keep vim from breaking (entering a newline) in the middle of a string?
I type in a list of strings, and it looks like this:

```
a=['a string', 'b string', 'c
string']
```

I like the line breaks, I don't want vim just to wrap the line and continue on the next editor line. I want my lines to be roughly 80 characters long without manually entering newlines.

What I want is either

1. Don't break any string, even if it has a whitespace
2. Break the string using implicit string concatenation, i.e. close the
       string and start a new string on the new line
3. Break just before 'c string'

The closest solutions I have found are not very useful:

[Is there any way to get vim to auto wrap python strings at 79 chars?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1314174/is-there-any-way-to-get-vim-to-auto-wrap-python-strings-at-79-chars)

[how to configure vim to smartly wrap python strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9472414/how-to-configure-vim-to-smartly-wrap-python-strings)

[Vim: Inter-String Line Breaking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15757298/vim-inter-string-line-breaking)

Currently 'J' is one of the most heavily used keys to fix broken strings.

Comment: Note: `:set tw=0` turns off word wrap altogether.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make vim not break strings when autoformating?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10615908/how-to-make-vim-not-break-strings-when-autoformating)

Comment: Thanks, Rob. That means you have to add linebreaks manually, doesn't it? So if I have a line with 70 characters and add some more to the beginning, I need to find the closest break to 80 chars by hand and then hit enter. I can't use gq, because it has the same problem.

Comment: @glts: it's a similar problem, he is asking about getting autoformat (gq) not to break strings, I would prefer to get the formatting done while typing. He points at the formatexpr, too, but that seems to be difficult and I didn't find any solution.

Comment: @Dan `gq` and formatting while typing use the same underlying formatting mechanism. Short of relying on an external tool, `'formatexpr'` really is the way to go. And as has been pointed out by others, writing the `'formatexpr'` is hard; you'll likely have to write it yourself.

Comment: @glts, I see. so the most practicable workflow is to set tw=0 and use an external program for formatting the entire file or blocks with gq. I'll look into the formatexpr, but it looks quite complicated and not well documented or used.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I do to wrap all lines at 80 characters without breaking any words, and preserve shorter lines:

```
:set formatoptions+=w
:set tw=80
gggqG
```

You can also use the following mapping to format current paragraph:

```
:nnoremap Q gqip
```

hope it helps.